# How can I break the law of non-contradiction in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, logic

The [law of non-contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_contradiction) dictates that two contradictory statements cannot both be true at the same time. That means that the expressions

```
(a && !a)
(a == !a)
(a === !a)
```

should always evaluate to a falsy value, and

```
(a || !a)
```

should always evaluate to a truthy value.

Fortunately, though, Javascript is a fun language that [allows you to do](http://wtfjs.com/) [all sorts of](http://wtfjs.com/2010/02/15/undefined-is-mutable) [sick things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715492/javascript-find-argument-passed-to-a-function). I bet someone a small fortune that it's possible to convince Javascript to break the law of non-contradiction, or, at least, convincingly make it look like it's breaking the law of non-contradiction. Now I'm trying to make all four of the above code examples give the unexpected result.

What would be a good way to go about this?

Comment: @djhaskin That sound like a question a programmer who only likes merely practical programs would ask.

Comment: You can just define a class in C++ and overload &&  to always return true. No?

Comment: @Patrick, Yes, in C, but Javascript doesn't have operator overloading.

Comment: Oh, so you mean JavaScript specifically. Gotcha.

Comment: @Peter: `==` doesn't correspond to logical equality. `===` is closer.

Comment: @outis Yes, I realize that. If somebody comes up with a solution that matches `===`, I will definitely be impressed at their JS-fu.

Comment: Here's an interesting exercise in tri-value logic: `(!(((0/0) && !(0/0)) == false) && !(((0/0) && !(0/0)) == true)) === true`. In other words, `(0/0) && !(0/0)` is an `a` st `!(a==false) && !(a==true)`.  Works just as well with `===`. Doesn't break logic the way you asked, but still...

Comment: @Peter: since `==` isn't the same as logical equality, finding an `a` st `a == !a` doesn't break logic, though it may be a step towards breaking transitivity of `==`.

Comment: As outis mention, using "==" will not break the law. Cause JavaScript is not type safe, it needs to convert values of different types to the same to compare them. So in the end you dont compare the same object but two objects that was created  by converting your original object by JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best I can do is:

```
[] == ![] // true
```

or

```
var a = []; 
a == !a
```

Of course this is really doing `[] == false // true` and `!![] == ![] // false`. It's really just a technicality.

EDIT: This is really a joke, but does work:

```
var a = false; var b = function() { return a = !a };
console.log(!!(b() && !b())); // true
console.log(b() == !b()); // true
console.log(b() === !b()); // true
console.log(b() || !b()); // true
```

Comment: So `[] == false` but `!![] == true`. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: As long as you use "==" JavaScript tries to convert the values to the same type. So in your example ![] will be converted to false and then JavaScript converts the empty array to '', which is falsy values in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

This one will do the trick:

```
var a = '0';
a == !a
```

(evaluates to `true`)

In this case, `a == false` and `!a == false`.

Comment: No it doesn't. You dont compare a with a, but a with !a. In JavaScript !a will convert to false, cause it's String and so, its a true value, which you convert to flase using !. Then you compare false with '0'. This will be converted to false by converting it first to a number which is 0, which is a falsy value in JavaScript. So in the end you compare false and false and not '0' to itself.

Comment: @eskimoblood By the process you described, the javascript engine will use the `==` (equality) operator to compare `a` and `!a`, and find that the two are not equal. The dynamic type conversion **is the reason** that expressions like this one in javascript can seem to violate simple logic, and I think this is the sort of example @Peter was looking for.

Comment: In my understanding it would only break if "==" would compare two objects by itself not the converted types.

Answer (score 2):

a=NaN;

```
var a=NaN, 
A=[(a && !a), (a == !a),(a === !a),(a || !a)];
alert(A)

/*  returned value: (Array)
NaN,false,false,true
*/
```

Comment: Those are all the expected values.

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't found anything to break `&&` and `===`, but here's one for `==` and `||`:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function() {
    return false;
};
a = {};
b = (a || !a);
alert(a || !a);  //alerts false
alert(b == !b);  //alerts true
```

Comment: That doesn't really break `||`. `a || !a` results in `{}`, which is still a true value. Also, you're adding an axiom that equates true values with a false value. The resulting inconsistency is one you create, not one that exists in JS.

Comment: @outis Yes, yes, I know. Actually breaking the law of non-contradiction, is, of course, impossible, so you have to be creative and just make it look like it does.